# awk printing against the condition

Tags: awk

I have a simple question but I could not figure it out.

I have a file that I want to print all the lines that DO NOT match the condition I specify in the awk if condition. But I can just get to print the condition, how the other would work?

This is my code:

```
awk '{if ($18==0 && $19==0 && $20==0 && $21==0) print $0}' file
```

I also tried this:

```
awk '{if !($18==0 && $19==0 && $20==0 && $21==0) print $0}' file
```

But the second one doesn't work, any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The negation (`!`) needs to be inside the parentheses:

```
awk '{if (!($18==0 && $19==0 && $20==0 && $21==0)) print $0}' file
```

And we add another set inside to wrap everything.

(FYI, if you had given how it "didn't work" (i.e., a syntax error on `!`, that would have been more helpful.  Please remember to include error messages or symptoms of something not working for future questions!)

Comment: Thank you! I also could solve it like this just now:                              awk '{if ($18==0 && $19==0 && $20==0 && $21==0) next;
else
print $0;}' file

Comment: @user1945881 you can `awk '!(a&&b&&...)' file`

Answer (score 6):

Here you can do:

```
awk '$18+$19+$20+$21!=0' file
```

`print $0` is not needed, since its default action.

Answer (score 0):

You could also reverse your conditional statement:

you want the opposite of :

```
awk '{if ($18==0 && $19==0 && $20==0 && $21==0) print $0}' file
```

Which can either be :

```
awk '{if ($18!=0 || $19!=0 || $20!=0 || $21!=0) print $0}' file
```

or

```
awk '{if (!($18==0 && $19==0 && $20==0 && $21==0)) print $0}' file
```

---

Example :

```
!cat file
A 0 0 0
B 1 1 1
C 1 0 1

awk '$2+$3+$4!=0' file
B 1 1 1
C 1 0 1

awk '{if ($2!=0 || $3!=0 || $4!=0) print $0}' file
B 1 1 1
C 1 0 1

awk '{if (!($2==0 && $3==0 && $4==0)) print $0}' file
B 1 1 1
C 1 0 1

awk '{if (!($2==0 || $3==0 || $4==0)) print $0}' file
B 1 1 1
```

Comment: This will not work, as it will print if any of these are met, not if all of them are.

Comment: Yes it will ! You may have misunderstood the question !

Comment: Do you want it to print if all the conditions are matched or just one of them ?